# synonym of "parking space"

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

> There is no nearby parking space left around this house.

Does *parking room* or *parking spot* sound correctly if it is used as a synonym in above sentence?

What is the synonym to use here if they are both not accurate?

Answer (score 3):

No I wouldn't use *parking room*.

*parking spaces* (plural) is probably OK, but more likely refers to a place with marked parking spots, usually in a business district or a parking lot.

> There were no **parking spaces** near the store.

When referring to parking in general, you can simply say

> There is no nearby parking left around this house.

*parking* is understood to be a place to park a motor vehicle.

*parking spot* refers to a specific place to park one vehicle, but I can't say if it applies to your situation.

> There is a **parking spot** next to the fire hydrant.

Comment: I wouldn't use _parking room_ either, but there would be nothing wrong with "There is no more _room to park_ around this house."

Comment: In New Zealand they refer to a parking space/spot as simply "a park". To my British ears it sounds very odd to arrive at a supermarket and "look for a park" - I used to scan for a wide open green space...

Comment: Yes, New Zealand English uses "car park" (or just "park") to describe the individual car-size space. NZE also uses the phrase "car park" to describe the greater paved area which contains many spaces.